# Converting a HttpServletRequest containing json to a POJO - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to use the poster add-in to send a json request.  I am sending the request to a function to read the json and create the InputDTO object.  This seems to run find but when i call the function to get the assigned value it throws a java.lang.NullPointerException error.  I found this tutorial and tried to use it. http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/11/how-to-create-a-simple-servlet-to-handle-json-requests/

It seemed like exactly what i needed but its not working.  Here are the code snippets for what i am doing.  Could someone please help with this?

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 try (PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter())
        {
            InputDTO inputJson = XMLReader.inputFromJson(request);
            pw.println("before the call to get timezone from the input DTO");
            pw.println(inputJson.getTimeZone());
            pw.println("after the call to get timezone from the input DTO");
```

here is the code for XMLReader.inputFromjson(request)

```
 public static InputDTO inputFromJson(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        InputDTO inputDTO = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();

            logger.debug("before the fromJson call");
            inputDTO = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), InputDTO.class);
            logger.debug("after the fromJson call");


        return inputDTO;

    }
```

The line that fails is the

```
pw.println(inputJson.getTimeZone());
```

The only methods that the InputDTO has is

```
public String getTimeZone() {
    return timeZone;
}

public void setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
    this.timeZone = timeZone;
}
```

This is the request i am sending:

```
{"request":[
{"timeZone":"CST"}
]}
```

Added: stack trace

```
Week3 threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.week3.Week3.doPost(Week3.java:136)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at com.ta.aa.dao.catalina.DAOValve.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.ta.aa.catalina.realm.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:631)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Please let me know if you can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: done. please see above.

Comment: That stacktrace doesn't match what you are saying. You seem to be calling `sendError` somewhere.

Comment: i see. there was a call to sendError in the catch statement.  I took that out im getting a null pointer now.

threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.homedepot.week3.Week3.doPost(Week3.java:136)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)

Comment: Please help us help you...What line is that? What is `null`? Is it the return value of `getTimeZone()`?

Comment: yes it seems to be the error out whenever getTimeZone() is called.  i have put a null check in before the line i thought was failing and its still throwing the error then.  is it possible its not properly getting assigned when i call tojson()?

Comment: I don't want to guess. Update your question. Add what your code currently looks like and the exception it's currently throwing and its message and stacktrace.

Comment: i have updated with the full stacktrace.  i didnt really edit any of the code other than removing the catch statement.

Comment: How do you expect Gson to parse the JSON you provided into the POJO you created?

Answer (score 0):

Names should match in the json and the class. The data you are sending in the json and your class definition do not match. Change your class definition.

```
class Request{

String tz;

public String gettz() {
    return tz;
}

public void settz(String tz) {
    this.tz= tz;
}

}
class InputDTO {

Request request;

public String getrequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setrequest(Request request) {
    this.request= request;
}

}
```

Comment: Although this is true, it doesn't address the root cause, as posted by OP.

Comment: And it still won't work. The root JSON object contains `request`, not `tz` or `timeZone`. And it contains a JSON array.

Comment: i changed this and took out the call to "sendError" that was mentioned above and i am getting a null pointer now.  i have posted part of the stack trace above

Comment: sorry i did that in the comments above.  its in the post now.

Comment: Looks like `inputJson` is `null`. And that is most probably because your mappings are incorrect. `inputFromJson()` is returning null. Correct you mappings.

Comment: You should fix your suggestions too @Aniket. Don't mix 2 options. Provide each fully. Right now you have JSON that doesn't match the POJOs.